# What is the counting complexity of random 2-SAT?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, counting-complexity, random-k-sat

Has any work been done on how the complexity of random instances of **#2-SAT** varies with the clause density? That is: how does *the difficulty of counting* satisfying solutions to a randomly generated instance of **2-SAT** vary, as the clause density varies? In particular, are there any rigorous results known involving critical thresholds?

Of course, because  **2-SAT** ∈ **P**, the typical counting complexity depends partly on the probability with which an instance is satisfiable; instances whose clause density is above the [critical threshold for SAT/UNSAT](http://pre.aps.org/abstract/PRE/v56/i2/p1357_1) will typically have an easy counting complexity, as the answer is "*zero*" almost surely, in the limit *n* $\to \infty$. However, the counting complexity may still be easy for instances of **2-SAT** having a density near to or just above the critical threshold for finite *n*: one might expect that a satisfiable instance will have only a small number of solutions, which might be easy to enumerate due to the tightness of the constraints.

For ***k*-SAT** with *k* ≥ 3, the [difficulty of determining whether an instance is satisfiable or unsatisfiable](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/selman/papers/pdf/96.aij.critical_behavior_cost.pdf)  seems to be highest near the critical thresholds separating the SAT phase from the UNSAT phase, in part as one tries to determine whether there exists *at least one* satisfying solution. For **#2-SAT**, the difficulty *cannot* lie in determining whether at least one solution exists; so one should expect that the difficulty is likely to be in determining the number of solutions for satisfiable formulae of a *significant but not large* number of constraints — that is, where there are enough constraints to induce non-trivial dependencies between variables, but not so many as to over-determine the possible assignments.

Comment: Good question. Not an answer, but it's interesting that for the 3-SAT decision problem the hardness threshold is at around m/n=4.26 (the same location as the satisfiability threshold), whereas for #3-SAT it's around 1.5 (see Handbook of Satisfiability or ). So even for $k \geq 3$ the counting complexity hardness threshold is away from the decision threshold. I would be interested in seeing whether any rigorous work has been done for general k.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps this paper can help you:

[New Worst-Case Upper Bound for #2-SAT and #3-SAT with the Number of Clauses as the Parameter](http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI10/paper/download/1672/1961) by J. Zhou, M. Yin, C. Zhou (2010).

And this one that studies the structure of the set of solutions of a random 2-SAT instance: [Satisfying Assignments of Random Boolean Constraint Satisfaction Problems: Clusters and Overlaps](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.107.8036&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by G. Istrate (2007)